# Dynamically sort list based off associated values with tie-breaker values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I'm trying to sort students based off frequency of participation. I have a table that is automatically generated totaling up how often a student has participated in the last few days. 
I want it to do 2 things that I can't figure out.

1. I want it to ignore students that are at 0 removing them from the resulting rankings.
2. The first number is most important but I want it to reference the next value in the result of a tie.

Short example of table:

```
Andy - 1 1 2 3
Brad - 0 1 2 3
Cade - 1 2 3 4
Dane - 1 1 1 2
```

Desired result:

```
Cade - 1
Andy - 1
Dane - 1
```

The tie-breaker isn't that important and I figure I can have conditional formatting to remove children at 0, but I still can't seem to figure it out. 
The closest formulas I have found in my searching are:

```
=INDEX($A$10:$A$9,MATCH(ROWS($C$1:C1),$C$1:$C$9,0))
```

This one doesn't work because it returns #N/A for pretty much all students who are tied.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:$C$9,MATCH(SMALL(NOT($C$1:$C$9="")*IF(ISNUMBER($C$1:$C$9),COUNTIF($C$1:$C$9,"<="&$C$1:$C$9),COUNTIF($C$1:$C$9,"<="&$C$1:$C$9)+SUM(--ISNUMBER($C$1:$C$9))),ROWS($C$1:C1)+SUM(--ISBLANK($C$1:$C$9))),NOT($C$1:$C$9="")*IF(ISNUMBER($C$1:$C$9),COUNTIF($C$1:$C$9,"<="&$C$1:$C$9),COUNTIF($C$1:$C$9,"<="&$C$1:$C$9)+SUM(--ISNUMBER($C$1:$C$9))),0)),"")
```

I had this formula that can handle ties but it needs to be OFFSET but I don't know how since it is an array formula. Also, with both these formulas it reverses the ranks with the lowest values at the top. If anyone could assist me I would greatly appreciate it. I'm doing this so that I can give all students a chance to participate equally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a helper column.  In that column put the following formula:

```
=IF(B1=0,"n/a",SUMPRODUCT(B1:E1/10^(COLUMN(B1:E1)-MIN(COLUMN(B1:E1)))))
```

This will return a single number based on the rankings.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Then in your output column use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(LARGE(F:F,ROW(1:1)),F:F,0)),"")
```

[image: ![![enter image description here]

Then a simple VLOOKUP to return the first number:

```
=IF(I1<>"",VLOOKUP(I1,A:B,2,FALSE),"")
```

[image: ![![enter image description here]

Comment: I figured I would need a helper column but couldn't think of what it would be. Turning the values into a decimal is such a clever and simple solution. This is great, however I am still having 1 problem with this part. '=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(LARGE(F:F,ROW(1:1)),F:F,0)),"")'
If the results are a tie to the very end it will return the same name multiple times. When changing the values so that Andy and Dane both have 1.123, it will rank Andy twice. [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0a1DA.png)

Comment: I have found a solution to the problem where I was returning the same name multiple times in case of a tie. I thought I would share it in case someone could use it in the future. I changed the first formula to  `=IF(B1=0,"n/a",SUM(-.0000000001*ROW(),SUMPRODUCT(B1:E1/10^(COLUMN(B1:E1)-MIN(COLUMN(B1:E1))))))` 
This way it adds a small value to the results but not enough to change the rankings. Probably not the most elegant solution but it seems to work. Thank you Scott Craner for getting me this far